# Jquery changing onclick on button

Tags: jquery, joomla

We are using a Joomla third party extension - Surveyforce and want to be able to change the click event on a button on a particular page on the survey so we can do our own checking before moving on.

We have created a module to put on the page containing jQuery code as follows

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('div#survey_container').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){

      if (jQuery('p#aaa').length >0){ // <<< CHECK WE ARE ON CORRECT PAGE

         alert('Do your processing here');

         if (jQuery('#sf_next_button').length >0){ // <<<CHECK FOR NEXT BUTTON

           alert('Do button processing here');
           jQuery('#sf_next_button').hide();

           alert (jQuery('input[type="button"][value="NEXT"]').attr("onclick"));
           jQuery('input[type="button"]  [value="NEXT"]').css("width","500px !important");

         }
      }

   }); 

});
```

It runs the code and displays the alerts but doesn't apply any of the actions like the `hide()` or the css.

Any help would really be appreciated
Thanks

Rich

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi Lodder, no errors - we get the alerts displayed but no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a `click()` method to bind the click event; in the handler, you can `return false` to cancel the default action. In code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    if (jQuery('p#aaa').length >0){ 
         jQuery('#sf_next_button').click(function() {
              // do your processing here
              jQuery('input[type="button"]  [value="NEXT"]').css("width","500px !important");
              return false; // so the default click action won't happen;
         });
    }
});
```